# Outlook not showing the toggle dark mode on/off button on the message window

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm trying to change the background color of outlook's message window. To do that, I'm trying to follow the official [instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dark-mode-in-outlook-3e2446e0-9a7b-4189-9af9-57fb94d02ae3), but I'm not seeing any of the buttons that are mentioned there. Does that mean I can't change the background of the message window to black?

I'm running Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11929.20618) 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to File > Options > General > Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office > Office Theme. Check "Never change the message background color".

For your reference: [Outlook 2019 reading pane doesn't turn dark](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d17a919e-d59f-4326-85ca-e2aacaf597b0/outlook-2019-reading-pane-doesnt-turn-dark?forum=outlook)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer...unfortunately, I don't have that option on this version (I'm only seeing the Office theme dropdown...)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to be valid anymore.

For me the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dark-mode-in-outlook-3e2446e0-9a7b-4189-9af9-57fb94d02ae3#:%7E:text=Toggle%20between%20dark%20mode%20on%20and%20dark%20mode%20off) provided by the OP has the right information.

- Reading a message you received

  - When reading a message, you can turn dark mode on or off by using the icon at the top of the message window.

    [image: toggle theme outlook in received message]
- composing a message

  - When composing a message, you can turn dark mode on or off from the Message toolbar by selecting the dark mode icon to change the message window to white or black.

    [image: toggle theme outlook in new message]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you would need to Uncheck "Never change the message background color",
as stated on the page referenced in the other answer:  Outlook 2019 reading pane doesn't turn dark